# Drupal 7 and Acquia what are these?

Tags: drupal-7, acquia

Would like to know what does Drupal 7 and Acquia have in common?
I am starting a personal website and trying to get the best out of free source.
My understanding is that Acquia is a superset filled with best and enhanced features of Drupal 7, so is acquia free to install and use say if i want to host my website on godaddy?
Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it pretty much right. Drupal is the base technology and Acquia is adding value by packaging and support. I think they also provide themes and a bunch of other stuff on top of Drupal. And it's free to use and host yourself if you want. I have not used them personally, but they have been around a long time so I think it's worthwhile to investigate what they have. The Drupal documentation is sometimes very hard to use, so there is significant value in having someone package collections of Drupal modules and provide additional documentation and support.

Answer (score 1):

Aquia also includes a stack installer for Windows, Mac & Linux (similar to MAMP, etc.) It is worth noting also that Acquia is the company co-founded by Dries Buytaert, the orignal creator of Drupal. Dries serves as the CTO of Acquia.